# Problemas com assets vindos de um JSON - Vuejs com Webpack

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Fala galera, beleza?

Alguém pode me dar um help? Eu tenho a seguinte estrutura de pastas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como minha aplicação é simples, não estou fazendo nada ligado a banco, vou consumir direto um arquivo JSON que terá as informações para popular minhas telas!

No caso do meu arquivo Cases.vue, tenho um v-for que popula as informações do meu data/cases.json, porém não estou conseguindo imprimir as imagens a partir das informações desse json, alguém pode me ajudar?

```js
{
  "cases": [{
    "behance": "https://www.globo.com",
    "bg_box": "bg_case_grandeshistorias",
    "logo": "./assets/images/cases/logos/uirapuru.png",
    "alt": "Colégio Uirapuru",
    "name": "Colégio Uirapuru",
    "description": "Grandes histórias começam aqui",
    "background": "../assets/images/cases/bg/grandeshistorias-bg.jpg"
  }, {
    "behance": "https://www.terra.com.br",
    "bg_box": "bg_case_building",
    "logo": "../assets/images/cases/logos/flir.png",
    "alt": "FLIR Systems",
    "name": "FLIR - Building Store",
    "description": "A melhor solução estrutural",
    "background": "../assets/images/cases/bg/building-bg.jpg"
  }]
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="container-fluid p_top_header relative">
    <div style="" class="bg_cases"></div>
    <div class="row relative">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4" v-for="case in records.cases">
        <a :href="case.behance" target="_blank" class="box_cases" data-bg="#case_pump">
          <div class="img_case" :class="case.bg_box"></div>
          <div class="content_cases">
            <div class="d_table h_full">
              <div class="d_table_cell">
                <img :src="case.logo" :alt="case.alt">
                <h4>{{ case.name }}</h4>
                <span>{{ case.description }}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export
  default {
    name: 'Cases',
    data() {
      return {
        records: require('../data/cases.json')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

No caso esse é o meu arquivo Cases.vue e o meu cases.json!

Alguém sabe me orientar como fazer para imprimir o logo(`<img :src="case.logo" :alt="case.alt">`) por exemplo?

Da forma que está ele dá o seguinte erro:
`1 GET http://localhost:8080/assets/images/cases/logos/empresa.png 404 (Not Found)`

O problema é que eu não consigo definitivamente descobrir o path real da minha imagem para colocar corretamente no meu json! Mas na minha estrutura física é em src/assets/images/cases/logos/logo.png.

Se alguém puder me ajudar eu ficaria grato!

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

o teu cases.json esta abaixo de src por isso ele não inclui isso como parte do diretorio, sendo que ../ sobe um nivel do diretório, então tem que levar em conto de onde que vc está consumindo o seu json ... se vc estiver consumindo de um diretorio superior a src inclua ele ... como seria o caso por exemplo se estivesse sendo executado no diretorio raiz ou em outra ramificacao de diretorio.

para testar se o diretorio corresponde

testa       "localhost" + /src/assets/images/cases/bg/case.logo  no navegador
para aparecer a imagem, se vc colocar a url inteira funciona, porém não é muito usual. bastando cortar a parte inicial de acordo com a pasta onde o script estiver rodando ... lembrando que se estiver em uma ramificação diferente vc deve subir ate a ramificação em que se encontre no caminho novamente usando ../ uma vez para cada diretorio e continuar o restante do diretorio normalmente. 
 espero que tenha conseguido explicar ;)